# JavaScript How to pass data from ajax(firebase data) to HTML

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**HTML**

```
  <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="page-header"><?=$title?></h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            <p>
                <ol id="valueList">
                aa
                </ol>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is my AJAX code this code doesn't show any error only the problem is doesn't show in the HTML**

```
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    database = firebase.database();

    var refDeleafing = database.ref('Deleafing');
    refDeleafing.on('value', gotDataDeleafing, errData);

    function gotDataDeleafing(data) {

        var blocks = data.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(blocks);
        console.log(keys);
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var k = keys[i];
            var deleafingBlock = blocks[k].deleafingBlock;
            var li = document.createElement('deleafingBlock');
            $(li).parent("valueList");
        }
```

**if i will use the li.parent("valueList"); it show an error parent is not a function. is there anyway how to work it?**

Comment: Are you using jQuery (likely enabled via codeigniter), with its method [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)? if not, which definition of `$()` is being used here?